# can not use http.begin() in HTTPClient Arduino Library to open my IP

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-httpclient

i have an esp32 cam with 192.168.1.54:8082 IP.
i want use from http.begin ("http://192.168.1.54:8082"); in  HTTPClient Arduino Library that not working while when i am using "http://192.168.1.54:8082" in a browser working fine.
any help can be useful.

```
#include <HTTPClient.h> 

HTTPClient http; 

http.begin("192.168.1.54:8082"); //Not Working Here (but in a browser 192.168.1.54:8082 works fine) 
int httpCode = http.GET(); 
if (httpCode > 0) { 
  String payload = http.getString(); 
  Serial.println(httpCode); 
  Serial.println(payload); 
} 
else { 
  Serial.println("Error on HTTP request"); 
} 
http.end();
```

Comment: this is my code ;

Comment: #include <HTTPClient.h>
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://192.168.1.54:8082"); //Not Working Here (but in a browser http://192.168.1.54:8082 works fine)

int httpCode = http.GET();

if (httpCode > 0)
{
String payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(httpCode);
Serial.println(payload);
}

else
{
Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
}

http.end();

Comment: Please do not put your code in a comment. Edit your question and put it there, properly formatted. See the help for how to format questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

The API for `http.begin(url)` assumed standard port of 80 or 443 is used. In order to use port 8082, you need to pass in the port as function argument like this:

```
http.begin("192.168.1.54", 8082);
```

Comment: i changed the format of use http.begin like this http.begin("192.168.1.54", 8082); but stiil problem not fix

Comment: What exactly the "problem not fix" means? Add `Serial.println(httpCode)` to find out exactly what error code you are getting, please do some debugging.

Comment: i found exactly what error code i am getting by Serial.println(httpCode)  so httoCode = -1